# integral $\int_0^{\pi} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, {\rm d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Evaluate , if possible in a closed form, the integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, {\rm d}x$$

*Basically, I have not done that much.* I broke the integral

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \left ( \frac{\pi}{2}-x \right ) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, {\rm d}x  &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left ( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right ) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, {\rm d}x  + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \left ( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right ) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, {\rm d}x\\ 
 &\!\!\!\!\!\!\overset{u=\pi/2-x}{=\! =\! =\! =\! =\! =\!} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{u \cot u}{\frac{\pi}{2}-u} \, {\rm d}u + \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \frac{u \cot u}{\frac{\pi}{2}-u} \, {\rm d}u\\ 
 &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{u \cot u}{\frac{\pi}{2}-u} \, {\rm d}u\\ 
 &\approx 2.13897
\end{align*}

I have no idea how to evaluate this. I was thinking of IBP and then some kind of Fourier , but I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the origin of this integral?  What makes you believe that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: @Dr.MV Well I found it at an integration marathon. By closed form I mean whatever kind. It many contain special functions for example.

Comment: where was this marathon, on AOPS?

Comment: \begin{align} u & = \frac \pi 2 - x \\  \\ x & = \frac \pi 2 - u\\  \\ \text{As $x$ goes from $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$, } & \text{ $u$ goes from $\frac\pi2$ to $0$.} \\  \\ du & = -dx \\  \\ \int_0^{\pi/2} \left( \frac \pi 2 - x \right) \frac{\tan x} x \, dx & = \int_{\pi/2}^0 u \, \frac{\tan\left(\frac \pi 2 - u \right)}{\frac\pi2 - u} \, (-du) = \int_0^{\pi/2} u\, \frac{\cot u}{\frac\pi2-u} \, du \\ \\ & = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac 1 {\displaystyle \left( \frac \pi 2 -u \right) \frac{\tan u} u} \, du \end{align}

Comment: The integral of this function is equal to the integral of its reciprocal, and I wonder if something should be made of that.

Comment: I suppose another way to put that is that if $f(x) = \left( \dfrac \pi 2 - x\right) \dfrac{\tan x} x$ then $f\left(\dfrac \pi 2 -x \right) = \dfrac 1 {f(x)}.$ Then tangent function itself also satisfies that identity, but I don't know a way of evaluating its integral by using that fact.

Answer (score 2):

**Too long for a comment.** We have the following representations:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, dx
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4} + \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \psi\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right) \sin(2\pi x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(e^{2\pi t} + 1)}.
\end{align*}

At this moment I have no good idea of dealing with these, though I am posting this in hope of providing an alternative start for others as well as for a self record.

Comment: It seems we can't use the digamma reflection formula to crack the first equality the one with the digamma integral. :( :(