# Nasty logarithmic infinite sums arising from a tan integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, logarithms, trigonometric-integrals

While trying to work on an old [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901305/an-improper-tan-integral), I managed after some manipulations to show that the nasty improper tan integral
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right) \frac{\tan x}{x} \, {\rm d}x\approx 2.138967
$$
could be represented as
$$
I=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\ln \left(\frac{2 k+1}{2 k-1}\right)}{2 k-1}-
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\ln \left(\frac{2 k-1}{2 k+1}\right)}{2 k+1}\ .\qquad(\star)
$$
The purpose of the original post was to find a closed-form solution for $I$. Clearly the problem would be solved if closed-form solutions for the (equally nasty) logarithmic sums in $(\star)$ could be found. I have worked a bit on those, but didn't achieve much. My question is: can the sums in $(\star)$ be evaluated in closed form? Many thanks, folks.